# MutableDictionary turns immutable

Tags: ios

In my first function i create an NSMutableDictionary and saves it in an array.

```
NSMutableArray* tempPlayersArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey: @"kgpsTempArray"]];
NSMutableDictionary *tempPlayerDictArray = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

if (!(userDeviceName)) {
    [tempPlayerDictArray setValue:userDeviceName forKey:@"DeviceName"];
}else{
    [tempPlayerDictArray setValue:@"empty" forKey:@"DeviceName"];
}
[tempPlayersArray addObject:tempPlayerDictArray];

[defaults setObject:tempPlayersArray forKey:@"kgpsTempArray"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

In my second function i get it as NSCFDictionary - which is not mutable.

```
NSMutableArray* tempPlayersArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey: @"kgpsTempArray"]];
NSMutableDictionary *dictionaryForSearching = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%@",[dictionaryForSearching class]);

dictionaryForSearching = [tempPlayersArray objectAtIndex:index];

NSLog(@"%@",[[tempPlayersArray objectAtIndex:index] class]);
NSLog(@"%@",[dictionaryForSearching class]);
```

The first log shows "NSDictionaryM".
The second log shows "NSCFDictionary".
And the third shows "NSCFDictionary" as well...

Can anyone explain me why? And how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NSUserDefaults works with inmutable objects, so that's the reason that when you return your dictionary it's changed.

You can try this:

```
dictionaryForSearching = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[tempPlayersArray objectAtIndex:index]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `NSUserDefaults` is free to copy, persist, and deserialize as it likes. Assume it does not return mutable objects. If you need a mutable object, make a mutable copy.

Answer (score 0):

Every thing depends from here:

```
NSMutableArray* tempPlayersArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey: @"kgpsTempArray"]];
```

Reading NSUserDefaults always give you Immutable object.